# Who created the default Ubuntu wallpaper?

Tags: design

Who created the default Ubuntu wallpaper? I mean [the wallpaper displayed at this link](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://www.ubuntugeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/default.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-10-10-maverick-default-wallpaper-new.html&usg=__wpDddJsaze0cnNYEA1FTigAtltU=&h=1280&w=1920&sz=891&hl=en&start=4&zoom=1&tbnid=EACAjfE-ag8KvM:&tbnh=100&tbnw=150&ei=Z6J5T_LGA87jrAf9zKGhDQ&prev=/search?q=ubuntu%2bdefault%2bwallpaper&hl=en&sa=X&biw=1366&bih=682&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&itbs=1).  It is beautiful and I am curious: was it Mark Shuttleworth himself?

Comment: Looks like a mix of the 10.XX wallpaper and the 11.xx, add to that the purple at the far right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a worf of the  [Canonical Design Team Blog](http://design.canonical.com/2010/08/second-update-to-the-ubuntu-light-themes/).

Update: Now that i've read a little, i believe Canonical held some sort of contest where users could contribute with artwork, Wallpaper competition i believe, and maybe some user won and got his wallpaper published.

You can read more here:

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/ubuntu-wallpapers/0.31.6
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-wallpapers/+bug/621287
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-wallpapers/+bug/625193
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/629216
- https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/design-m-wallpaper-competition

Comment: The wallpaper contest ones are in addition to the default wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

The default wallpapers in Ubuntu since 10.04 have been made by [Otto Greenslade](https://launchpad.net/~otto-chaotic) ([Portfolio](http://chaotic.co.uk/)).

Prior to 10.04, the wallpapers were mostly created by [Ken Wimer](https://launchpad.net/~kwwii) ([Blog](http://kwwii.blogspot.com/)). I say "mostly" because my memory is a bit hazy if he created every single older wallpaper, but he was the designer of the wallpapers prior to 10.04.